# cannot get array values from a form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update all table  rows  using one  submit form ,and  I find this  way  that  i make  the  name  of  the  input  implement  an  array but  I can't get  it's  values plus I'm getting undefined index for foo array.
my code:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal form-row-seperated"  
     enctype="multipart/form-data"   action="updateSetting.php"  method="post">

        <div class="portlet">

            <div class="portlet-body">



             <?php    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>




                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $row['title_en'] ?>
                        <span class="required"> * </span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input   type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                               value="<?php echo $row['value'];?>" name="foo[<?php echo $row['setting_id']; ?>] "


                        >
  <!--                            <input type="text" name="foo[--><?php //echo $row['key']; ?><!--]" value='--><?php //echo $row['key'];?><!--' />-->


                        <span class="help-block"></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php   } ?>


            </div>

        <div class="portlet margin-bottom">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-lg" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Edit
            </button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>


       </form>
```

updateSetting.php

```
  <?php $value=$_POST['foo[]'];




    foreach ($_POST['foo'] as $key => $value) {

      $sql1 = "UPDATE settings SET value='$value' WHERE setting_id='$key'" 
      or 
      die(mysqli_error());
      $result1 = mysqli_query($sql1);
      }
        echo "update complete";
```

can any one  tell me what's  my mistake or  give  me  another  suggestion to update  the  rows  in one  form ...thanks  in advance

Comment: Find out the structure of `$_POST['foo']` by doing, `print_r($_POST['foo'])`, then loop over it accordingly. Your also open to sql injection and XSS.

Comment: What issue are you getting? Is there any error?

Comment: Note: You're currently having `or die(mysqli_error())` after you're creating a string.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['foo']` change to `foreach ($_POST['foo[]']`

Comment: This row: `$value=$_POST['foo[]'];` is redundant and should actually throw a "undefined index"-notice. Have you checked your error log? A good idea is also to turn `display_errors` on in your local PHP environment. Read more here: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @BrianGottier When posting a form containing arrays, you just access it with `$_POST['foo']`, not `$_POST['foo[]']`. The `[]` simply makes the values into an array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm getting "undefined index" but when I loop over  foo  I get this:

      Notice: Undefined index: foo[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\tfs\MilkMan\admin\includes\pages\updateSetting.php on line 1

Notice: Undefined index: foo[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\tfs\MilkMan\admin\includes\pages\updateSetting.php on line 4

6 times

Comment: So you are getting errors? You need to edit your question to include _all_ errors and what actually happens when you run your code. And that error is for the first row, that I mentioned.

Comment: @BrianGottier foreach  invalid  argument  you can't do this

Comment: Remove `$value=$_POST['foo[]'];` from starting

Comment: @B.Desai can you see my comment to Magnus? where should  I put  it ? sorry  but  it's  the  first  time  that  i tried  to pass  an  array

Comment: So remove the first row. It's an invalid key and not needed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If  I remove  it   so how  to get  foo  values?

Comment: You are already getting the values in your foreach-loop: `$_POST['foo']`. You're not actually using the  `$value` from the first row. You're using `$value` from your loop (which actually would _overwrite_ the initial `$value`). You should read up on how [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) actually works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh sorry  i got  it ... i forget the  $_post into the  foreach

Comment: Remove the first row that throws that error, then change your code according to the answer you got from @B.Desai below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php code should be as below. After executing query it will throw error not after assigning query to string. Also in mysqli you need to pass connection object in `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_error`

```
foreach ($_POST['foo'] as $key => $value) {

      $sql1 = "UPDATE settings SET value='$value' WHERE setting_id='$key'" ;

      $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or  die(mysqli_error($con)); //need to add error here
      }
    echo "update complete";
```

Comment: i've tried  it  but  i get  this:
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\tfs\MilkMan\admin\includes\pages\updateSetting.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tfs\MilkMan\admin\includes\pages\updateSetting.php on line 11

Comment: Its database connection object replace it with your connection object